# vsftpd - ftp user cannot create folders

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd

CentOS - I have created an ftp user that can log in remotely over the internet to the vsftpd server.

Now I can log in via ftp, see all the directory listings (not limited/jailed) to any directory, but I **cannot create a new folder** inside `/var/www/html`

When I want to create a new directory, it fails:

```
550 Create directory operation failed
```

Note, that I have done the following:

```
chmod 775 as well as chmod 777
```

as the root user on the server itself (using putty).

How do I get write access to a specific folder for an FTP user?

**Note**: I have the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 6 david root 4096 Jul  7 20:30 html
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you typed

```
write_enable=yes
```

in your

```
/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

otherwise you could use

```
chroot_local_user=yes
```

for ftp users being able to login as local users. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Identify file `vsftpd.conf`

Edit it: `vi /etc/vsftpd.conf`

and then uncomment(#) the line: `write_enable=yes`

and finally, restart vsftpd: `service vsftpd restart`

Comment: It is already answered. Nothing new.

Comment: But above answer, it not easy to understand for new member go to linux OS

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this. In `/etc/vsftpd.conf` add or uncomment these:

```
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
```

Then, `systemctl restart vsftpd`